# ruby - watir-webdriver - Typing speed is INSANELY slow

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-11, watir, watir-webdriver

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
b = Watir::Browser.new :ie
b.goto "google.com"
b.text_field(title: "Search").set "ABCDEFG"
```

When running the above code I run into an issue where Watir takes SIX seconds to type one character, and then takes SIX seconds to type the next character and so on. This happens every time. I've searched up and down in the documentation for Watir and haven't found a way to increase this typing speed. There used to be a `Watir::Browser#speed` method but I've searched through the source code and found no references to `speed`.

I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456906/how-to-control-test-execution-speed-in-watir-webdriver-with-the-watirbrowsers) but it's no longer helpful :<

I must use internet exploder for this, because of DCOM :<

```
RUBY_VERSION => 2.3.1
Watir::VERSION => 0.9.3
IE Version => 11.494
IEDriverServer => 2.53_1 x64
```

Comment: Try the 32-bit version of IEDriverServer.  FWIW: https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium-google-code-issue-archive/issues/5116

Comment: Some have had luck by changing the `requireWindowFocus` setting - see http://stackoverflow.com/a/32691070/1200545

Comment: @orde Fixed it! Thank you so much the six seconds a char was driving me nuts.

Comment: You can also object.value = "ABCDEFG" and set the whole field at once rather than typing.